# laravel4 form validation errors

Tags: forms, validation, error-handling, laravel, laravel-4

I use laravel4 form my application in which users can store some data with post form to database. When i post blank form i got error NotFoundHttpException.
I have in HomeController

```
public function create()
{
    $validation = Producer::validate(Input::all());

    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('home/create')->withErrors($validation->errors());
    } else {




        $producer = new Producer;
        $producer->title = Input::get('title');
        $producer->body = Input::get('body');
        $producer->url = Input::get('url');

        $producer->save();

        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

model

```
class Producer extends Eloquent {

public static $rules = array(
    'title'=>'required|min:5',
    'body'=>'required|min:10',
    'url' => 'required'
);

public static function validate($data) {
    return Validator::make($data, static::$rules);
}
```

and view

```
@if($errors->has())
   <ul>
     {{ $errors->first('title', '<li>:message</li>') }}
     {{ $errors->first('body', '<li>:message</li>') }}
     {{ $errors->first('url', '<li>:message</li>') }}
   </ul>
@endif
   {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'create')) }}
     <p>{{ Form::label('title', 'Název služby') }}</p>
     <p>{{ Form::text('title') }}</p>
     <p>{{ Form::label('body', 'Popis') }}</p>
     <p>{{ Form::textarea('body') }}</p>
     <p>{{ Form::label('url', 'Adresa webu') }}</p>
     <p>{{ Form::textarea('url') }}</p>
     <p>{{ Form::submit('Přidat',array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}</p>
   {{ Form::close() }}
```

but when i run this script i obtain error `NotFoundHttpException`. Where is a problim in my code in route?

my routes

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');

Route::get('/detail/{id}', 'HomeController@detail');

Route::get('/add', 'HomeController@add');

Route::post('/create', 'HomeController@create');
```

now i have

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');

Route::get('/detail/{id}', 'HomeController@detail');

Route::get('/add', 'HomeController@add');

Route::post('/create', 'HomeController@create');

Route::get('/create', 'HomeController@create');
```

and

```
if ($validation->fails()) {
  return Redirect::to('/create')->withErrors($validation);
} else {
```

an still same problem

solved i have big mistake i redirect to bad rout i need to use  HomeController@add because this make View for the form

Comment: Can you post the relevant routes from routes.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route `home/create` doesn't exist. Check your routes, it should be `/create`. Another problem, you need a route for `create` that handles `get`. At the moment you only have one for post.

Comment: If I just pass validator that produce the same error I think the problem is in my route